# UIProgressView with custom ProgressImage stretched incorrectly. How to fix?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uiprogressview

I' m trying to customize `UIProgressView` with custom progress image. But it is stretched incorrectly.
So i have a custom progress image : [image]

its dimensions are 75x18 pixels. And I have a track which length is 270 points. But when I set my progress image its corner radius after filling the track became wrong. I tried to set `resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake (0,0,0,1)` but then image began to repeat and not to stretch. How can I fix this?

Comment: `UIEdgeInsetsMake (8.0, 10.0, 8.0, 10.0)`

Comment: @Desdenova is there some way to preserve corner radius the same?Because after this it became more and more sharper

Comment: I shouldn't, I'll check. Do you need to stretch height as well or only the width?

Comment: @Desdenova Only the width. I want to fill with it the whole track

Comment: this is retina right? Add the retina suffix to the image and you are all set. `imageName@2x.png`

Comment: But do not use it in the code. `[[UIImage imageNamed:@"g21hU.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 10.0, 8.0, 10.0)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIEdgeInsetsMake` protects the pixels at the given values.

Red marker shows the stretchable area for `UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 10.0, 8.0, 10.0)` (top, left, bottom, right)

[image]

Another thing is, always name your retina images properly even if you don't use the non retina versions for the older devices, like `imageName@2x.png`. Otherwise it will mess up it's scale.

And call it like this without the retina suffix:

`[[UIImage imageNamed:@"g21hU.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 10.0, 8.0, 10.0)]`

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I understood it at last)